# Increase max header size in play framework 1.5.x

Tags: playframework-1.x, request-headers

We're finding the following error in our client play 1.5.x framework application

```
25 mag 2020 15:18:34  ERROR ~ Request exceeds 8192 bytes
```

It is related to the header size (we tested it with a curl with a header bigger than 8kb).

We didn't find in the official documentation how to increase the accepted header size in default play http server.
We tried with

```
-Dhttp.netty.maxHeaderSize=65536
-Dhttp.netty.maxInitialLineLength=65536
-Dplay.server.netty.maxInitialLineLength=65536
-Dplay.server.netty.maxHeaderSize=65536
```

but none of these seem working (probably because they are play 2.x config).
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue to this today and we solved with the following:

```
-Dplay.server.akka.max-header-value-length=128k
```

Posting for posterity in case someone else run into the same problem.

Comment: Play 1 does not use akka, so this is probably something about Play 2.